# App Crashes with "Getting info from XYZ" when accessing settings pane. Limit of entries reached?

Tags: crash, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, application-settings

a user of my app reports that the app crashes when accessing the settings charm. The charm shows the text "**Getting info from** ". After A while the text changes to "**Can't get settings for this app right now**" and a little while later the app is terminated.

After several thousand downloads from the Store this is the first time, that such a problem is reported. During the development of the app I came accross a similar problem: When I tried to add more than 7 setting entries in OnCommandsRequested() the app showed the same problem and crashed with an exception:

> The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)
>
> Too many SettingsCommand items have been added to the Settings pane.
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.Append(T
>   value) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToCollectionAdapter.Add[T](T
>   item) at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdControl.onAdSettingsCommandsRequested(SettingsPane
>   settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs eventArgs)

It seems that it is not allowed to add more than 7 entries to the settings pane and the app crashes because the Advertising SDK tries to add its privacy statement.

After I discovered this limitation I removed one entry from the settings and the problem was solved.

How is it possible that this problem shows up in the store version of the app although the number of entries has been reduced? How is it possible that (as far as I can tell) the problem only shows up at one device while it works without any problem on thousands of other devices?

**A theory**:

Could it be, that (for some reason) the system tries to add another entry to the settings on this devices and thus triggers the problem? What kind of entry could that be? Why is it not added on other devices?

Thank you very much!